# == and isEqualsToString giving strange behavior

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, equals

I have below code

```
NSString *firstName = @"1.6.1";
NSString *secondName = @"1.6.1";

if (!(firstName==secondName)) {
    NSLog(@"lock the app");
} else {
    NSLog(@"do not lock the app");
}

if (!([firstName isEqualToString:secondName])) {
    NSLog(@"lock the app");
} else {
    NSLog(@"do not lock the app");
}
```

Output I am getting is

```
do not lock the app
do not lock the app
```

However when I use actual values for `firstName` & `secondName`, I get output as

```
lock the app
do not lock the app
```

Below are details of `firstName` & `secondName`

```
 // this is coming from server
 firstName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"iPhoneAppVersion"];

 // this is coming from app version from iPhone
 secondName = [self appNameAndVersionNumberDisplayString];

- (NSString *)appNameAndVersionNumberDisplayString {
    NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
    NSString *appDisplayName = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
    NSString *majorVersion = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
    NSString *minorVersion = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
            minorVersion];
}
```

If I print `firstName` & `secondName`, I get values as `1.6.1`, `1.6.1` respectively.

Any idea why there are two different outputs when using equals?

Comment: There could be a (hidden) space character at the beginning/end of what you've received from the server. Try logging the strings' lengths, too.

Comment: @Cyrille : I checked and lengths are same and no space character...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get different behaviour for `==` and `isEqualToString:`. Because `==` operator compares only the address of object and `isEqualToString:` will compare string value.

You should not use `==` for string comparison.

Comment: I do understand that, but why for the first code it works? where I am assigning values manually?

Comment: Constant string literals (like `@"1.6"`) are given the same memory address by the compiler, when you use them more than once.

Comment: Yes, constants string are handled in different ways, If you use constant at ore then one place, all will have same address as compiler have given them same memory address.